# VSC Jenkins Jack plugin on Windows ARM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been using the Visual Studio Code Jenkins Jack plugin on Windows Intel systems for some time and now wanted to do this on an Apple M2 with Parallels Windows 11 VM.

VSC and plugin installation as usual, but when trying to set up a connection this error occurred

```
> Error running command extension.jenkins-jack.connections.add: command 'extension.jenkins-jack.connections.add' not found. This is likely caused by the extension that contributes extension.jenkins-jack.connections.add.
```

I tried to add the directory of the extension to the path variable, but without success.

```
C:\Users\arne\.vscode\extensions\tabeyti.jenkins-jack-1.2.1
```

Any idea what else I could try or a suggestion for a similar plugin to control Jenkins from VSC?

Thanks and best regards

Arne